# Paypal checkout integration in android app

Tags: java, paypal, ide

I'm trying to integrate paypal checkout in my android app. In this, I don't know how to put my application ID in the part:

BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "://paypalpay",

Could someone help me?

PayPalCheckout.setConfig(new CheckoutConfig(
this,
YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
Environment.SANDBOX,
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "://paypalpay",
CurrencyCode.USD,
UserAction.PAY_NOW
));

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you have nothing to do here it will automatically pick your application id. you just have to add your application id in paypal developer sandbox account in login with paypal advanced settings.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).